# Silent result with two identical files in diff: how to show them?

Tags: shell-script, diff, file-comparison

When I set the `-s` parameter, `diff` also print files, that are different.

```
diff -s $FIRST_FILE $SECOND_FILE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What do you want to happen when files are identical? What do you want to see when they are not identical?

Comment: I want to display message, when files are Identical.I solved this problem, by using $?, but maybe there is another solution

Comment: do you mean something like `diff a b >/dev/null && echo different`?

Comment: @terdon if that's all that's desired then [`cmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html) would be a better tool.  `cmp -s file1 file2 && echo identical`  (Also, you wrote `different` instead of `identical`...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution may be:

```
diff -s $FIRST_FILE $SECOND_FILE > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "The files are identical"
fi
```

NOTE: It changed the question text.

Comment: As has been pointed out, `cmp` really is better in this case, because it won't waste time trying to construct a nice patch.

Comment: I base my answer on the instructions given. I thought he needed to use diff something I know about what he wanted to do. Naturally, it is better to use cmp.

Answer (score 14):

The Unix philosophy is to have one tool per job, and the shell to glue them together. So: one tool to compare, and one tool to get the desired output format.

In this case, the output format is sufficiently simple that this part can be done directly with the shell.

To compare two files, if you're only interested in whether they have the same content and not in listing out the differences, use [`cmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cmp.1.html).

```
if cmp -s -- "$FIRST_FILE" "$SECOND_FILE"; then
  printf '%s\n' "$FIRST_FILE = $SECOND_FILE"
fi
```

Comment: This isn't completely valid in my opinion. I wanted to use `cmp`, however `cmp` (at least version 3.8) doesn't have a recursive flag, whereas `diff` does, so I cannot use comp to check recursively the content of folders, which I currently need to.

Comment: @CasperBang Comparing directory trees is not a problem that this answer was trying to solve. The scope of this question was only comparing files. Depending on what you want to do, using `find` to recurse may or may not be easy (it depends what you want to do about files that only exist on one side).

Comment: Yes I understand. It was merely as a nugget of knowledge for others who came looking for the same as I did, as I agree with you, but played around with cmp without success. `diff` has a well defined way of handling this case, also for directories, which was what I was after.

Answer (score 7):

By default, `diff` is silent when given identical files; that's the only aspect of its behaviour that `-s` changes. So it always compares files, and outputs differences; with `-s` it also outputs a message when files are identical, without `-s` it doesn't mention identical files at all.

You can get the behaviour I think you're looking for by combining `-q` and `-s`; `-q` instructs `diff` to only indicate that files differ (when they do), without detailing the differences.

Here's an example:

```
$ echo 1 > a
$ echo 2 > b
$ echo 2 > c
$ diff -qs a b
Files a and b differ
$ diff -qs b c
Files b and c are identical
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it, but i want, that it print only identical (ignore differ)

Comment: @FezZ - nothing stopping you to pipe this to `sed '/ differ$/d'`

Answer (score 0):

I have put quotes around the filenames, you should also change the filenames to lowercase.

```
diff "${FIRST_FILE}" "${SECOND_FILE}" > /dev/null && echo "Same"
```

Comment: Good point about filenames to lowercase but you didn't explain why.  @FezZ, by convention all-caps variable names in `bash` are for environment variables only.  For non-environment variables you should use lowercase names.